# how to select identical rows in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

The dataset that I'm looking into has an id for the incident, but a few columns (a_dttm, b_dttm, and c_dttm) have dates and times that appear more than once. I looked into it and found that even though the ids are unique, there are entire rows that look almost identical.

So without having to go through 200 rows of potential identical rows, what can I write in postgres to search for rows that are identical in a_dttm, b_dttm, and c_dttm?

This is what I've been doing to select the identical rows one by one:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE a_dttm::timestamp = '2007-01-13 08:29:35'
order by a_dttm desc
```

I got the timestamp from another query.

I know if these three columns are completely identical, then the rows are for sure duplicates.

Comment: If this is a `postgresql` question, why put `mysql` tag? Please remove uncessary tag.

Comment: For example: `select array_agg(id) as ids, a_dttm, b_dttm, c_dttm from data group by a_dttm, b_dttm, c_dttm having count(*) > 1;`

Comment: If the table has a(useful)  Primary Key, duplicates would not be possible. Constraints are your friend. Question: is `id` a (surrogate) PK ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select count(*), a_dttm, b_dttm, c_dttm 
from data 
group by a_ddtm, b_dttm, c_dttm;
```

This should tell you how many duplicates you have.

Comment: Is there a way to locate the duplicates? Thanks!

Comment: @Dave - Simply add a HAVING clause to the end: `HAVING count(*) >= 2;`

Answer (score 0):

This will select all the rows for which (at least one) other row exists, with the same {a_dttm,b_dttm,c_dttm}, but with a different id:

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM the_table t
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT*
   FROM the_table x
   WHERE x.a_dttm = t.a_dttm -- same
     AND x.b_dttm = t.b_dttm --same
     AND x.c_dttm = t.x_dttm --same 
     AND x.id <> t.id        -- different
   );
```

---

Similar, but now actually DELETING (some of) theduplicates:

---

```
DELETE 
FROM the_table t
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT*
   FROM the_table x
   WHERE x.a_dttm = t.a_dttm -- same
     AND x.b_dttm = t.b_dttm --same
     AND x.c_dttm = t.x_dttm --same 
     AND x.id > t.id        -- different (actually: with a higher id)
   );
```